# Force nuget to use .net framework 4.0 assembly instead of 4.5

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have a project mixing .NET 4.5 and 4.0 projects.

Every time When I update Newtonsoft.JSON or add a new package, the 4.5 projects will reference different builds than the .NET 4.0 projects:

```
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="net40" />
```

and the .net 4.5 projects reference the 4.5 build:

```
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

The 4.5 projects however reference the 4.0 projects, causing the build to fail on TFS build (because it builds all in 1 folder) and when the Newtonsoft.Json .NET 4.5 build ends up in the build folder before the .NET 4.0 projects build, causes the projects targeting .NET 4.0 to fail.

Is there a way to force `update-package` to pick `targetFramework="net40"` for all projects in the solution (even if the project targets .NET 4.5) (without having to find-and-replace in files after each update)?

So similar to what you can do with the install-package -version?

Comment: NuGet picks the assembly based on the target framework of the project and as far as I am aware you cannot override this behaviour. How do you get it to work with install-package?

Comment: @MattWard I do a find-and-replace after updating or adding a new project in the *.csproj and packages.config to point everything to .NET 4.0

Comment: It's a pain when a package contains differently named DLLs for each framework version. Messes up installers, leaves leftover files... it's a mess. Would be nice to be able to override this so when you update your framework version, it won't cause the extra side effects.

Comment: Just extract the .Net4.0 version of json.net and add a static reference to it, getting rid of the NuGet package alltogether.